# Why does display: flex cause elements to go upside-down?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have CSS styling for a container `<ul class="pillars">...</ul>` and i added display: flex; to fit the pillars in the container and fit their width like so

```css
.pillars {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  vertical-align: unset;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.pillars .pillar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
.pillars .pillar.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pillars">
    <li class="pillar">Lorem</li>
    <li class="pillar">Ipsum</li>
    <li class="pillar">Dolor</li>
    <li class="pillar">Sit</li>
    <li class="pillar">Amet</li>
</ul>
```

But `display: flex;` is causing a side effect where the pillars are upside down as seen below:
 [image: Picture of pillars upside down]
Pillars are the black bars above the gray background, they are supposed to look like:

[image: Picture of pillars in correct format]

Comment: Try rotating the container  by 180 degree with css -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: rotate(180deg);

Comment: @Ajith That could work however, i'm still wondering why this occurs and is there something i'm missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code was working as expected. By default flexbox aligns its items at `flex-start`, which means the items display at the top of a fixed height container. By adding `align-items: flex-end` to your flexbox, you will get the desired result:

```css
.pillars {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  vertical-align: unset;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.pillars .pillar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  width: 20px;
}

.pillar:nth-child(3n) {
  height: 200px;
}

.pillar:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  height: 250px;
}

.pillar:nth-child(3n -2) {
  height: 150px;
}

.pillars .pillar.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pillars">
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
  <li class="pillar"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, i hope your answer can help people who have this problem in the future.